# Trouble with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm having a problem running the below script. I'm trying to call a server side method on a button click using jquery. but its not working.I'm neither getting a success nor failure alert to check the script. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var xml="";  // Scope limit covered but not working
  $('#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function(event) {
     xml = "<schedule>";
    $("#selectedcolumns").find("tr").each(function() {
      xml += "<data>";
      xml += $(this).find("td").eq(1).html() + "\n";
      xml += "</data>";
    });
    xml += "</schedule>";


   //PAgeMethod
    PageMethods.GetCustomer(
        xml,
        function(result) {
          alert('success:' + result);
        },
        function(result) {
          alert('error:' + result.get_message());
        });

    alert(xml);

  })
});
```

In CodeBehind:

```
[WebMethod]


 private void GetCustomer(string NoOfRecords) //just need to reach here.


  {
   xmlfile(NoOfRecords);
  }
```

Comment: try using firebug: http://getfirebug.com/ to help debug your javascript and post/respoonses it's critical for troubleshooting ajax funcationality.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scoping issue for the xml value (You declare it in the scope of the callback -- so it will not be visible out side that function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var xml = "";

  $('#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function(event) {
    xml = "<schedule>";
    $("#selectedcolumns").find("tr").each(function() {
      xml += "<data>";
      xml += $(this).find("td").eq(1).html() + "\n";
      xml += "</data>";
    });
    xml += "</schedule>";

 //This method is defined in the codebehind
  PageMethods.GetCustomer(
    xml,
    function(result) {
      alert('success:' + result);
    },
    function(result) {
      alert('error:' + result.get_message());
    });

    alert(xml);  
  });
});
```

Comment: OK, then update your code and show what you have tried.  At the same time show the code for `PageMethods.GetCustomer` which is missing in your original post.

Comment: I think the page methods code is there in the post. I did only this much in my page and dont know whether any other codes should be written to make this work.

Comment: No in the post is the calling of PageMethods.GetCustomer -- not the code of that function.

Comment: That's there in the codebehind part. Please forgive me if i get you wrong.

Comment: The code behind won't be able to access the xml variable.  They are on two different machines.

Answer (score 0):

`WebMethod`'s need to be declared static. [Here is a good guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/karan/archive/2010/09/12/calling-server-side-method-using-jquery-ajax.aspx) covering calling server side methods from jQuery.

Comment: I was following the same article and met some issues with the json data. I'm new to jquery and dont know how to rectify the problem :(

Comment: WebMethod's in an .asmx do not need to be declared static (only ones used in .aspx).

Comment: My apologies, should have looked closer. I wasn't aware that it wasn't using the .aspx "code behind".